# My MacOS color-pallette seems "flattened," and I don't know why

Tags: color

(MacOS Big Sur, MacBookPro fairly-latest, experienced user)

Recently, I find that every display of an image on my Mac, whether in a pro app like FinalCut or an ordinary browser display, seems to be "flattened:" the available color palette seems to be greatly reduced. I find that I can't illustrate this problem to you because any image which I send to anyone else looks quite normal – so the problem of course is not in the image.

No matter which profile I select in "System Preferences...Display...Color," I see exactly the same effect: the display of any image that I now see is exactly as though the color palette had somehow been squeezed into "256 colors or less."  And yet, outside of these program windows, the "MacOS taskbar" appears quite normal.

Comment: Have a look in System Prefs > Accessibility > Display

Comment: I already considered this, based on other responses, and there is nothing checked there.  Quite honestly, the visual appearance is as though there were no more than *sixteen* colors there.  Hell, maybe no more than *eight!*  And yet – no other display, including this web page, shows any problems at all.

Comment: You need to give us something solid to go on. You’re just repeating the same vague info